# Что такое класс-менеджер в коде?

Tags: ооп

Имею лишь интуитивное понимание что такое менеджер в коде. И это самое интуитивное понимание, к сожалению, не помогло доказать свою правоту при споре с дипломным руководителем, однако он тоже не смог мне внятно объяснить что он понимает под данным термином.

Вообщем ищу правду, так сказать, за ссылочки на определения (таковых я к сожалению не нашел) буду очень благодарен, ну и ваше личное мнение по этому вопросу.

В догонку хочу спросить является ли, по вашему мнению, класс с набором методов, реализующих небольшую логику (превентивные проверки, аля существует ли данный проект, авторизован ли пользователь и т.д.) и заносящих данные в БД, менеджером?

Comment: Вот нехватает описания того интуитивного понимания, чтобы ответить. Менеджер чего? А тот, что вдогонку как будто не класс-менеджер, а класс-Бог

Comment: Мое интуитивное понимание: менеджер - класс, обладающий информацией о предметной области, ну и производящий операции с данными (например, каким-то образом их изменяя) или взаимодействуя с устройством. Короче говоря он знает как сделать что-то с управляемым объектом, но ему не достает для этого данных, эти данные к нему приходят извне через его интерфейс. Но менеджер это не просто транслятор входных данных в команды управляемого объекта, он обладает какой-то логикой, например, производит проверки не нарушится ли логическая целостность БД (то что нельзя или не приемлемо, сделать на уровне БД).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В некоторой мере вы правы! Но всё-таки класс менеджер, это не тот кто на прямую взаимодействует с данными, а так сказать посредник. То есть у вас есть классы типа репозиторий которые общаются с вашим данными, а менеджер занимается тем что инкапсулирует в себе обьекты этих классов. И в любом месте программы вы можете обратиться к менеджеру и получить от него нужный обьект нужного репозитория, и не будите плодить их во многих местах засоряя код!

Comment: хм, база данный фактически мне возвращает то что я прошу. Я же не лезу в фаил БД, не парсю таблицу и не достаю/записываю данные. Я хочу сказать что менеджер напрямую с данными и не работает, он является посредником между "кем-то" и БД. или я опять что-то путаю? Менеджер просто знает как спросить у БД так, чтобы "кто-то" получил именно то что попросил.

Comment: Так оно и есть, просто менеджер является высшим узлом над всем что работает непосредственно с БД а тот кто "просит" что-то обращается не на прямую к репозиторию а к менеджеру!Опять же, чтобы не плодить лишних сущностей!